# Cannot invoke "com.company.restapi.dal.AssignmentRepository.findAll()" because "this.assignmentRepository" is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to create an integration test for my `AssignmentRepository`. However the AutoWiring is not working.

Code (`AssignmentRepositoryTest`):

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = RestapiApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

public class AssignmentRepositoryTest extends ContainerEnvironment {
    @Autowired
    private AssignmentRepository assignmentRepository;

    @Test
    public void When_GetAssignments_Expect_EmptyList() {
        List<Assignment> list = (List<Assignment>) assignmentRepository.findAll();
        assertEquals(0, list.size());
    }

}
```

Code of `AssignmentRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface AssignmentRepository extends CrudRepository<Assignment, Integer> {
    List<Assignment> findAllByUserId(@NotNull(message = "No userId given") String userId);

}
```

I get the following error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.company.restapi.dal.AssignmentRepository.findAll()" because "this.assignmentRepository" is null

I'm using Java with Spring Boot, Spring Boot test & Testcontainers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I managed to resolve it after close to 4 hours of fighting.
It seems like the issue was with the @Test annotation, I was not using the one provided by jupiter, but rather the one below.

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

It worked when I changed it to.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

I hope this helps.